# Twilio Flex UI - Getting Started Sample Project Does Not Work

Tags: twilio

Has anyone been able to the twilio flex ui sample project to work.  I followed all of the instructions as indicated on https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin.  The sample project is not ready to be implemented as it does not have a start in the package.json.  I have added "what I think" is the required items in order to get it work, but I continually get errors and have not able able to get it to work.  Does anyone have instructions besides what is provided in the above link?

I installed the sample project per instructions.  I tried various versions of node.  I am currently on 14. i have read through each of the errors after the various iterations and attempted to rectify eac, but still not working.  I believe the instructions are outdated.

Comment: Can you please add the detailed error message that you get and also describe the step?
Please note that the [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin) explicitly says:
> A Node.js long-term-support (LTS) version installed (type node -v in your terminal to check):
v16 recommended for Flex UI 1.x
v17 recommended for Flex UI 2.x